# Linq set null to a value with automapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I have a ticket that contains messages. Also, the ticket model contains a a resolutionMessage that is a message that can be nullable.

I want to do something like that :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, TicketModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionMessage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
            {

                if (src.ResolutionMessageID != null)
                {
                    src.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageID == src.ResolutionMessageID);
                }
                else
                    // Return null;
                }
                ));
```

Second attempt :

```
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionMessage, opt =>
                {
                     (opt.MapFrom(src => if(src.ResolutionMessageID != null) 
                      opt.MapFrom(src => src.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageID == src.ResolutionMessageID));
                else
                    opt => opt.Ignore();
                }

                );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will consider `ResolutionMessageID` is a nullable type, you can try something like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionMessage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionMessageID.HasValue ? src.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageID == src.ResolutionMessageID) : null));
```

If it is not a nullable type and allow null:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionMessage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionMessageID != null ? src.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageID == src.ResolutionMessageID.Value) : null));
```

Or you use `opt.MapFrom()` or `opt.Ignore()`, there is not way to use both. I think it is better keep the null value when the condition for you map does not accept the rule. If you use, `opt.Ignore()` will ignore the property on conversion of objects.

Comment: ResolutionMessageID is nullable type. It seems what I need but unfortunately I still need to do opt => opt.Ignore(); because the automapper seems to don't like null values... There's a way to do it with opt.ignore()?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **AfterMap** MappingExpression in AutoMapper and then check for **null** value.

- AfterMap(Action<TSource, TDestination> afterFunction);

Example:

```cs
 // Execute a custom function to the source and/or destination types after member mapping

CreateMap<Resource, SubjectResource>()
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
              {
                if (src.Subject.English == null)
                {
                  dest.Subject.English = Enumerable.Empty<SubjectResourceList>();
                }
              });
```